# How to reinstall bootloader after migration to SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd, grub, multi-boot, debian-wheezy

I must say, it was difficult to name this question.

Basically, I need to properly reinstall the bootloader on my system, because I already have the working system disks for my OSes.

The long story is this: I had the large slow HDD with Windows7 & Debian Wheezy dual-boot on it, perfectly bootable. Then, I ordered the SSD drive and prepared my system partitions to fit onto the much smaller SSD. I wanted the following schema:

```
128 GB Windows
 24 GB /     on Debian
 86 GB /home on Debian
```

Strange size for `/home` because there's no such thing as true 256GB disk drive.

So, I've prepared such a partitions on my initial HDD and installed the new SSD and then I loaded the GParted live USB (can't remember now how it was really named), and then just copypasted the partitions from HDD to SSD.

So, now I have the following partitions across the physical disks:

```
SSD
   128 GB copy of original Windows partition
    24 GB copy of presumably Debian /
    86 GB copy of presumably Debian /home

HDD
   128 GB Windows
    24 GB / on Debian
    86 GB /home on Debian
    ... several other partitions with non-system data ...
```

And the behavior of the system right after the Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V in GParted was as follows: no GRUB, system boots right into the Windows on HDD.

In BIOS settings are to boot from SSD first.

I managed to create the Debian Testing installation USB and loaded it into the rescue mode, found that it identified my SSD as /dev/sda and installed the GRUB to the /dev/sda. Now my system loads the GRUB which lists both Windows and Debian. From HDD. So, I am now back into initial position.

Please, how I should set up the GRUB so it'll load the OSes correctly from SSD?

Should I fire up my Debian, fiddle with the GRUB's config and reinstall it again to the same place (at SSD)?

Answer (score 2):

First, use FIXMBR and FIXBOOT from Windows installation disk on Windows partitions. Next, install GRUB for Linux starting, which should add also Windows partitions as the ones that can be booted by GRUB. In GParted look which partitions are **active** - active should be Linux bootable partition (in your case / ) and Windows with "boot" folder.

System boots to Windows on HDD because he can't boot to SSD - there are no active partitions or the boot-loader on these partitions is not properly set.

You can set active partitions using GParted. Next, you should run GRUB (from Live DVD or USB or DVD with Linux - your distro) to set up booting for Windows and/or Linux partitions.

Everything you do - remember to operate on SSD drive. Do not touch HDD.
Always backup your data prior to partitions and bootability changes.